# How can I define a variable in Powershell with value from selection?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I've tried to use the function [`Out-Menu`](https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Out-Menu.ps1) for playing around with PowerShell.
So far it works but now I wonder how I can create a variable based on the users selection.
If I have an array `$colors = 'blue', 'white', 'red'` and provided the user selects `1. blue` from the resulting list.
How can I get his selection ***"blue"*** into a variable let's say `$uChoice`?

```
$color = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the color (blue, white, red) !"
Write-host "Color is: " $color  
If ($color -eq "blue") {
    $country = 'Germany'
} elseif ($color -eq "white") {
    $country = 'United Kingdom'
} elseif ($color -eq "red") {
    $country = 'France'
} else {
    Write-host -ForegroundColor Red "Unknown color - please check your input !"
    exit
}
# So now I can continue with $country
```

Comment: If you're using that function to store the choice in a variable you would do something like this `$uChoice = $colors | Out-Menu` I think. Not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: This doc will probably answer your question. [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Meanwhile I removed the Out-Menu function and instead of creating an array I created a couple of If elseif statements based on the users input. The user has to enter the correct color and depending on his input my variable is filled with the correct value.
I provided the sample code in the original question.
@Santiago - thanks for your hints

Comment: Good to know! Remember, you can use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.1) whenever you have lots of `if ... elseif ...` its easier to read and more elegant :)

Comment: By the way, there are no "dumb questions" when someone wants to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are keen to learn I leave you something for you :)
Lots of new concepts for you to learn here:

```
Remove-Variable userChoice, country -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Clear-Host

while(-not $country)
{
    try
    {
        [validateset('blue','white','red')]
        $userChoice = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the color (blue, white, red) !"

        $country = switch($userChoice)
        {
            blue {'Germany'}
            white {'United Kingdom'}
            red {'France'}
        }

        Write-Host -ForegroundColor $userChoice "Choice was: $country"
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Unknown color - please check your input !"
    }
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile I continued to work on my script and actually I'm not interested in setting any colors - it's been just an example.
Actually I'm working on user homeshares and try to correct ACLs partially struggling with wrong order of ACEs as there is an explicit Deny set.
I could solve all probs but have to use two scripts calling the second one from the first one.
What is not clear to me is if I try to run a function within the first script it fails; if I copy this function to the second script and call this script from the first one it works.

Comment: @Jogi99 I recommend you to ask a new question explaining what you just wrote here as well as your code. Hopefully someone will be able to help you.